While opening a new query window or any object from SSMS, it says "Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime ,Version=6.0.0.0
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (mscorlib).
When trying to open a query window or click modify a stored proc or create script of any obj table/view etc ,I get the above error. I am able to connect to the sql server instance alone but further not able to proceed with anything.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What version of SSMS?

used 19.1 and now 20.2. getting same error in both versions

try to run a repair for SSMS.
